# How to confirm user password in the cheapest way

Tags: php, cakephp

I need users to confirm their current password before editing some information. Comparing it with session auth information is supposed to be the best way but the current password is not stored in the auth session. The only way that I can think of solving this is to find the user by id and retrieve their current password to compare but I think the query is too expensive. Is there a better way?

Comment: You really shouldnt worry so much about the costs. they are totally irrelevant in a use case like changing the password. Tip: What you are looking for is implemented here using `'current' => true`: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ - as a behavior solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I am not going to answer the question in the way you want, instead I will help you with proper standards of escalating a users "role" or "powers" if you will to do such things as edit, delete ect. ect. ect.

1. You should not be using a session to store a password.  (ever, ever, ever!)
2. When doing user look-ups, for password storage, logging in, what have you, do a query on the database - This is not to "expensive" as you say it. I have a database with upwards of 2000 (which is relatively small, really small...) rows and it is handling that without even breaking a sweat!
3. Do not use a Cryptographically broken password functions like MD5, SHA[1,2]. Those functions were not specially designed for Password storage. Instead use crypt functions in particular [Bcrypt](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which uses the Blowfish Cipher. Which was made for proper storage of passwords.